# Copy locked dbf file on windows using python

Tags: python, windows, dbf

Well, almost everything is in title. I have a dbf file which I would like to copy even if it is locked (edited) by another program like DBU.

If I try to open it or copy with shutil.copy I get

```
>>> f = open('test.dbf', 'rb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.dbf'
```

I know that it is locked on windows level because I am unable to copy it witch batch or with windows explorer. But is there any method to copy such a file?

Comment: DBF files are *BINARY* files. Open them with `'rb'`

Comment: You probably can't copy a locked file in win.

Comment: @John Machin , you are right. Opening with 'r' flag will cause data to be damaged and i fixed it in code, but still cannot find solution to copy locked file.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that file locking was invented for a purpose, like stopping people getting an inconsistent or damaged copy of a file that was being updated?

Comment: a real database has a way to recover that fuzzy copy without any problems, if you can apply the transaction logs over the copied database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't. Even if you were to circumvent the locking mechanism, another process might be in the middle of writing to the file, and the snapshot you would take may be in an inconsistent state.

Depending on your use case, [Volume Shadow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) might be of relevance.

Comment: Yeah, after few days of research i must agree. It seems that only way to make copy of locked file is to make shadow copy using for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530725%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool from **Joakim Schicht** that copies any locked file.
The only issue is that some AV tag it as malicious, when it is not.
Depending on your use case, this can be a solution.

https://github.com/jschicht/RawCopy